# PHP: Error Base de datos no seleccionada

Tags: php, html, mysql

Disculpen, tengo este pequeño problema que no eh podido resolver, tengo un sistema web al cual le quiero hacer actualizacion en cierto momento por medio del mysql_query, pero me dice que no tengo la bd seleccionada

Este es el código de conexión a la base de datos y si se dan cuenta tengo la selección de mi base de datos.

```
     $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "proyecto_terror";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    mysql_select_db("proyecto_terror");

Y Aquí tengo el resto del código que es donde hago mi select y mi update para que se actualice en la fila que yo deseo

$nick2 = $_GET["nickP"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nick = '".$nick2."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$datos = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $datos[] = $row;
$passA=$_POST["passA"];
$passR=$_POST["passR"]; 



if ($row["password"]==$passA) {
mysql_query("UPDATE usuario SET password = '$passR' WHERE id_usuario = '$row[id_usuario]'");
echo mysql_error();
}else {
    echo "no coinciden";
}

    }
```

Y esto es lo que me sale en la pantalla al dar clic en actualizar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Actualizacion

---

Resolví este problemas y se debió principalmente a que estaba usando dos diferentes maneras de manejar la información, en este caso usaba mysqli, para la conexión y mysql para la actualización, simplemente estandarice en uno solo, de preferencia usar mysqli, por seguridad.

Comment: Intenta enviandole como segundo parametro la conexion que abres, mysql_select_db("proyecto_terror", $conn); aunque te recomiendo que no uses funciones mysql, mejor usa mysqli o PDO, ya que con mysql tienes mayores posibilidades de sufrir ataques de inyeccion sql. Ademas no mezcles los drivers, en un lado usas mysql y en otro mysqli.

Comment: @David: Creo que convendría escribir eso mismo que actualizaste como una respuesta (no editando la pregunta), y agregando el código de la solución. Más información: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Te sugiero que como bien dice Mariano agregues tu solución como una respuesta marcándola como acertada y lo quites de la pregunta; para que los usuarios (que puedan tener el mismo problema que tu) la encuentren fácilmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysql_select_db("proyecto_terror");
```

Sí la variable $conn es la conexion usando mysqli deberías usar en el select_db mysqli de igual manera, para usar el select_db en mysqli puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->select_db($dbname);
```

Con eso ya el problema debería quedar resuelto...